# Data connection between excel workbooks: File opens when refreshing connections

Tags: excel, vba, connection

I’m attempting to migrate an existing excel sheet from using links to using data connections to other excel workbooks (Excel 2010).  Upon switching my first couple cells, I refreshed the connection to test it out, and while the cells populated just as I’d hoped, excel actually opened the sheet I was connecting to on top of the sheet I was working on.  I did see a suggestion somewhere that implied making it a shared workbook would help, but to make the data connections work as desired, I had to create a table on a background tab, so sharing the workbook is not possible.

Is there a way to suppress the sheet I’m connecting to from opening up?  I don’t want to go too far down this rabbithole if it’s always going to do this.

Bonus:  VBA code for automatically refreshing links every few minutes when the sheet is open, if it’s possible (rather than having the user press a button at will), may prevent me from having to migrate over to using connections to begin with.  I’ve just not had much luck finding any that might work so far.

Please let me know if you require further clarification!  Thanks!